# Set two default featured images

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I use the featured image in a few places in a theme I'm creating and I'm wondering the best way to set a default featured image. I need a thumbnail variant and then a 'full size' version, both using different images.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin. I found it after one search on google

https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image/